# Neo4j 2.3.3 Shell refuses square braquets

Tags: shell, neo4j, copy-paste

I am new to Neo4j, and installed zip 2.3.3 on Windows 7 64 bits.

In the (java)shell I was unable to type (via keyboard or on-screen keyboard) square bracquets [], and got a beep instead. About 2 years ago Andreas has asked the same question, but the post did not help me.

Copy/paste from notepad removed the bracquets and what was inside it: example match (n)-[r]->(p) return n,r,p; is copied as neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n)-->(p) return n,r,p; and gave the expected error message.

Please advise.

Comment: Playing around some more I discovered that typing or copying two left square brackets [[ is interpreted as a single [. Unfortunatly this does not work for the right square bracket.

Comment: First time I heard this, is this also the case in the normal windows command shell?

Comment: Michael.Both the PowerShell and normal command shell accept all special characters,like []